# How important is it to keep up with Ruby patch levels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

I run a lot of rails apps and I just want to know if I should be upgrading ruby as the new patch levels are released?

Comment: which version of rails you are using ?

Comment: @RemonAmin Rails 2.3.18 and 3.2.12

Comment: By patch levels, do you mean the p-xyz number at the end of a MRI release?  They're mostly bug fixes (including security and stability) and should be a good idea to keep up (they shouldn't be breaking any code unless the code depends on buggy behavior).

Comment: **By patch levels, do you mean the p-xyz number at the end of a MRI release** --> yes that's what I meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Ruby patches are specifically for security issues, then I would make these a priority to upgrade as soon as is possible.  Having a good test suite makes this process much less stressful.

The more nuanced answer is that you should read the security releases and decide for yourself, but security issues are notoriously hard to think through the implications for.  So the rule of thumb is to Just Upgrade!

The worst case if you don't upgrade is that Bad Guys will exploit the loophole (because they can read security releases too), and gain access to your servers, steal your customer email and password database and delete all your data.

Suddenly the process of upgrading doesn't sound so difficult!

As a shameless plug, I'm building a service to alert you when your current Gems and Ruby version needs to be patched, so you won't forget.  Sign up for early access at http://www.rubyaudit.com